# Selenium ide usage with internet explorer

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to clarify the thing that whether i can record the web application in internet explorer using selenium ide. I am able to record it in mozilla firefox but my question is whether i can do the same in internet explorer

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **record** it within the IDE using IE, because the IDE is *only* a Firefox plugin.

You will, however, be able to export the tests from the IDE to a particular language (say, Java) and then use WebDriver to **playback** those tests on IE, but this is not **recording**.